# run web flutter don't see network image

Tags: flutter

When I use `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer=canvaskit` in flutter web I do not see image (network image)

`flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer=canvaskit`

This is what i see: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGf1q.png)

Comment: try with --web-renderer html

Comment: I am need flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer=canvaskit

Comment: then add the images as local and add them to the asset folder instead of accessing them through an internet URL. Read about it in the answer below that they should be from the CORS policy configured. There are workarounds but they will take more time.

Answer (score 0):

Read
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/renderers

and

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/web-images

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)
CORS is a mechanism that browsers use to control how one site accesses the resources of another site. It is designed such that, by default, one web-site is not allowed to make HTTP requests to another site using XHR or fetch. This prevents scripts on another site from acting on behalf of the user and from gaining access to another site’s resources without permission.

When using , , or , the browser automatically blocks access to pixels when it knows that an image is coming from another site and the CORS policy disallows access to data.

WebGL requires access to the image data in order to be able to render the image. **Therefore, images to be rendered using WebGL must only come from servers that have a CORS policy configured to work with the domain that serves your application.**

**So if you want to still use canvaskit import them to assets folder and use it as a local asset**